# Express rendering templates not working inside the sub folder of views?

Tags: node.js, express

Here is the picture of my project structure.
[image]

I am trying to render the add.handlebars when the user visit the route `/ideas/me`
.Here is my code.

```
app.get('/ideas/add',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('ideas/add');
})
```

I understand this is really silly question but when I visit that route it gives `Error: Failed to lookup view "ideas/add" in views directory "D:\@Mock Up Sites\vidjot\views"`.I can fix this easily by telling the template engines to look in all the subfolders of views. But Why this is not working. I am heck sure the directory is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add following line in your app.js

```
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/'));
```

Comment: One problem it says path is undefined

Comment: npm i --save path